# Is it possible to handle error boundariesfor specific component in Next Js 13.4 app directory

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am trying to handle error in error.js but it shows the error for the whole page.  I have three components on the home page: User list, Product list and Testimonials.  Somehow the User list throws an error but the other two are OK.  So i want to show the error on the User list section only . is it possible in next js 13.4 app dir?

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unPH5.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.